# Sitecore: How to access same field name in different sections

Tags: sitecore

I have data template dt1 in sitecore that has the field "header" in section "data".
I also have data template dt2 that has the field "header" in section "portal"
Finally I have data template dt3 that uses both dt1 and dt2 as base templates.

How can I, in xslt, find the content of portal/header?

In my code, when I write <sc:text field="header" />, I get the content of data/header (since this node comes first).
I know how to do this in .net, but I need to use xslt.

/callprat

Comment: When asking how to compose a particular XPath expression to select specific nodes in an XML document one must provide the XML document itself. Please, do provide the XML document from which you want to select nodes. Also, describe well exactly which nodes you need to select.

Comment: Thanks, but that is one of the problems, I don't know what the xml looks like. 
I noticed that the code part of my question wasn't showing, I have edited that and as you can now see I'm using a sitecore's own vesion of xslt.

If someone knows a way to view the sitecore-xml this will probably also help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

And frankly I don't know of any supported way to do it from .NET either.

This, straight out of the [Data Definition Reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/datadefinitionreference-a4.pdf), section 2.1.1

> 2.1.1 Data Template Fields
>
> A data template field defines the user
>   interface control and other properties
>   that influence how the field behaves
>   in the Content Editor and Page Editor.
>   For more information about fields, see
>   Chapter 4, The Template Field.
>
> Note When defining field names, ensure
>   that they are unique even between
>   field sections. Both XSLT and .NET
>   code use field names alone, without
>   reference to sections, to extract
>   content from fields.

Comment: You can do it with the API. You just need to find the fields ID, by looking for it under the Section info. You can then use that to get the field value.

Answer (score 9):

I found a way around this in .Net on a project I was working on.  One of the templates that the client had set up had "Buckets" which had different field sections, but the fields within were the same between buckets.  I used LINQ to group the fields by Section name, then dealt with each grouping of fields.

```
var sections = currentItem.Fields.GroupBy(field => field.Section);
foreach (var section in sections)
{
    if (section.Key.StartsWith("Bucket"))
    {
        buckets.Add(new Bucket(section)); //I made a bucket item, 
                                          //and passed each IGrouping<Field> to it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
item.Fields.Where(field => field.Section.ToUpper() == "META DATA" && 
                           field.DisplayName.ToUpper() == "TITLE").First().Value;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can reference fields by their IDs:

C#:

`string value = item["{00000000-0000-0000-000000000000}"]`

or

`Field field = item.Fields["{00000000-0000-0000-000000000000}"]`

I haven't tried this, but I think it'll work in XSLT as well:

`<sc:text field="{00000000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />`